# Fail to build f# compiler on window 7 got "System.OutOfMemoryException"

Tags: f#

When compile the Fsharp compiler,as https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp told

1 using

```
build.cmd -noVisualStudio
```

got 8 error,some like

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
```

my pc have 12G memory.I think its sufficient.Is there some config file I have to edit so I can use all of my pc's memory?

2 using

```
build.cmd
```

got "System.Version have no new method"

can you teach me how to fix them?Thanks!

Comment: Is your Windows 7 the 32-bit version or the 64-bit version?

Comment: 64-bit.Is there a F# compiler version only on .net core?maybe it can compiler easier

Comment: I love Windows 7, but my guess is that at this point building the F# compiler on Windows 7 is very "unsupported".